# How to create a custom setup msi package / wix toolset / custom action

Tags: c#, installation, wix

I'm new in coding and in developing solutions for my customers. I need to create a c#-winform application in VS, which is able to generate a msi-Toolset. But the application is not the problem.

I wanted to create a pre-defined "default" product.wxs file - which will be build to a msi Package from  candle+light.exe via cmd.

The *.wxs should be able to: create filepaths, copy my defined files (1x.msi, 1x.config, 1x.cmd) and after install - execute the batch.cmd in admin context.

In Detail:

1.) I want to copy a existing msi File to an defined file path
2.) Run the batchfile in admin context:

- msiexec /i file.msi /qn
- delete the config file which was created during installation
- move my copied config file to installation path

In my wxs I tried to execute an install.exe which is just calling the batchfile - but it doesn't work for me. When I try to execute with rightclick - run as admin - it works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Version="5.0" Language="1033" Name="InstallConfigPackage" Manufacturer="ABC">
        <Package InstallerVersion="300" Compressed="yes" />
        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="MyApplication.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
        <Property Id='REINSTALLMODE' Value='amus'/>

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
                <Directory Id="MyApplicationFolder" Name="Manufacturer">
                    <Directory Id="MyFirstSubDir" Name="MyApplication">
                        <Directory Id="MySecondSubDir" Name="Version">
                            <Directory Id="MyThirdSubDir" Name="Files"/>
                        </Directory>
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <DirectoryRef Id="MyThirdSubDir">
            <Component Id="app.config" Guid="*" Win64="yes">
                <File Id="app.config" Source="MySourceFiles\app.config" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
            </Component>
            <Component Id="application.msi" Guid="*" Win64="yes">
                <File Id="application.msi" Source="MySourceFiles\application.msi" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
            </Component>
            <Component Id="batch.cmd" Guid="*" Win64="yes">
                <File Id="batch.cmd" Source="MySourceFiles\batch.cmd" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>

        <Feature Id="CONFIG" Title="CONFIG" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="app.config" />
        </Feature>
        <Feature Id="MSI" Title="MSI" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="application.msi" />
        </Feature>
        <Feature Id="BATCH" Title="BATCH" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="BATCH.cmd" />
        </Feature>

        <Binary Id="install.exe" SourceFile="MySourceFiles\install.exe"/>
        <CustomAction Id="install.exe" BinaryKey="install.exe" ExeCommand="/s" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" Return="check" />

        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="install.exe" After="InstallFiles">Not Installed</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>

    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: MSI has a mutex that prevents one msi from installing another.

Comment: You have to use a [bootstrapper application](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/) to install multiple packages.